# Unity, scrub camera animation using touch

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to scrub through an animation using touch? basically fast forwarding and rewinding the animation based on which direction your finger moves on the screen (x or -x)?.

I've managed to achieve this using the mouse but it was a kind of hack tbh. I used a slider to control the animation time with

```
anim["CameraPath"].normalizedTime = slider.value -= touchSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
```

but i couldnt get this working with touch.so now I'm trying to achieve it without using a slider and just have a touch drag on X or -x control the animation time.

any help is grealty appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use Touch.deltaPosition.x to do this. May be like this(Code not tested but should work):

```
float scrubVal = 0;

if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved){
    scrubVal += Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.x;
    scrubVal = Mathf.Clamp(scrubVal,0,maxScrubVal);
    anim["CameraPath"].normalizedTime = scrubVal;
}
```

**Edit**
After quite a long conversation, here's the solution that worked:
https://github.com/ahmedfawaz/C-Unity-Scripts/tree/master/TouchScreenCameraScrubbing

Comment: Hey thanks for your input on this. I'll try the code once I'm at my computer tomorrow morning and report back.

I'd just like to ask why you use mathf.clamp? Does this clamp the value from initial touch to end of touch? 

Also do you have any advice for a novice coder? When being faced with scenarios like this, what's the best way to figure it out? I tried looking at the unity API but it would never have occurred to me to to use a float, increment it, clamp it then plug it into the animation. Perhaps this is something that comes with experience...

Comment: 1. There's a minValue and maxValue in slider. As, you used slider previously and it worked, that's why I manipulated the scrub like a slider. So, there's a minValue(0 here) and a maxValue(maxScrubVal).
2. Honestly, googling is the best way. you can find almost all the answers I guess. You just need to know how to search efficiently. And obviously there's experience...

Comment: I guess that makes sense, thank you for clarifying. Yeah I constantly Google search,just sometimes it's hard when you aren't googling the right stuff.. 

If you don't mind, how would I add inertia to this script? You don't need to write the code but perhaps explain the logic and I could try code it. E.g. after you let go of scrubbing, the animation plays for a few more frames and slows down to a stop instead of stopping abruptly.

Comment: Without directly adding deltaPosition.x, you can Lerp the value with time and then add that lerped value in scrubVal. Lerp gradually changes the value from current value. That may have the effect of having some inertia. You can take a look at here for reference: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html

Comment: when you say "lerp the value" are you referring to the value of scrubVal or scrubVal += Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.x;?

Comment: Apologies if you got a million notifications....im trying to paste my code to show you what ive done so far but this comment box wont allow me to do so properly... but here is a snippet of what ive written so far: `scrubLerp = Mathf.Lerp(scrubVal, touchSpeed, smoothTime) * Time.deltaTime;
anim["CameraPath"].normalizedTime = scrubVal + scrubLerp;`

Comment: This isn't working unfortunately, I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. If you don't mind could you help me figure it out?

Comment: Can you share your code? Also, an example of the effect you are trying to achieve? What is happening now?

Comment: Yes sure I can but I'm not at my computer atm so tomorrow morning I'll send over all the details. Do you have skype? Perhaps we can chat there

Comment: We can chat here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/
In the mean time, are you looking for this kind of effect?
https://imgur.com/a/hZJA3
Rotation of the box is actually an animation.

Comment: Oh perfect, I'm clearly too new to stackoverflow lol. Yes that pretty much the functionality but when you release the drag it would continue to animate and gradually stop.

Comment: So, may be like this: https://imgur.com/a/dZYvw ?
Also, I just found out, you will not be able to chat in stackoverflow(minimum 20 reputation needed). **zayed.upal** is my skype.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to achieve!! How did you figure this out? I've been racking my brain over it all day to no avail. I will add you on Skype. If would be amazing to go through this with you. Also if you ever need anything art related I'm here to help as I'm an experienced 3d artist :)

Comment: Glad to know. Surely, I will. Here's the script I wrote to test it: https://pastebin.com/QWpxz74t
Couldn't test in a real touch device, only tested in editor.

Comment: I added you on skype, my username is Ahmed Fawaz.  I tried your code but it doesnt seem to work when i replicate your scene, is there a specific way you have setup your animation? is it legacy? using animation? set to play automatically?

Comment: Yes, it's a legacy animation in my case. Currently a bit busy. Will get back soon.

Comment: no problem take your time, ill be on skype when you're free :) i appreciate your help with this. Thank you

Comment: Hey i managed to solve it! i ammended the code slighly to get it working :) https://github.com/ahmedfawaz/C-Unity-Scripts/tree/master/TouchScreenCameraScrubbing

Comment: Great. However, I haven't get your request at skype yet. I am editing my answer with your script. Please mark the answer as correct. I love those reputation points :P.

Comment: Hey sorry yesterday was a crazy busy day setting up some new pcs. I marked it as answered, you definitely deserve the rep points! I sent you a request, I'll cancel it and try again today :) also I mentioned you helped me with the script on my github readme, is there a specific website you'd like me to point to? I've done it to your stackoverflow profile.

Comment: Hi Zayed, did you ever get my skype invite? i've resent it today :)